# how to get the value from ui.Chart.image.series

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I print a chart in the Earth Engine code editor using `ui.Chart.series`. I would like to extract the values of this chart using the Earth Engine API in Python to produce my own chart with matplotlib.

here `l8` is any `ee.imageCollection` having 'cloud and 'NDMI' band and point is a `ee.Geometry.Point`.

```js
var buffer = point.buffer(30);
print(ui.Chart.image.series(l8.select(['cloud', 'NDMI']), buffer, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30));
```

Is there a function to extract the data as a `ee.list` or a `ee.dictionary` or can I found somewhere what is under the hood of this function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is map a function over `l8` that reduces the bands over `buffer` and then adds the reduced values as an image property (i.e. metadata). I would then use `.aggregate_array` to get a list of those properties for the entire image collection. To get the dates, don't forget that javascripts timestamp are in milliseconds.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime

def reduce_bands(image) : 
   stats = image.select(['cloud','NDMI']) \
    .reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry=buffer, scale=30)
   return image.set(stats) 

l8 = l8.map(reduce_bands) 
cloud = l8.aggregate_array('cloud').getInfo()
ndmi = l8.aggregate_array('NDMI').getInfo()
dates = l8.aggregate_array('system:time_start').getInfo()

# convert to datetime 
dates = [datetime.fromtimestamp(d//1000.) for d in dates]
```

where `cloud` `ndmi` and `dates` are `list`'s.

Comment: that's exactly what I did, I wanted to wait until tomorrow to make an answer but you were faster. I'll wait to see if anyone come with another idea